# How does my $10\times10$ abacus work?

Tags: arithmetic, calculator

How does this $10\times10$ abacus work? More specific:

- Counting: is it common to count from 1 to 100, or from 1 to 9.999.999?
- How does addition work?
- How does multiplication work?
- Are there any other "fast methods" to do arithmetic?

[image: 10x10 abacus]

Comment: Though an abacus *is* a combinatorial object, learning the basics of how to do arithmetic with one is not exactly a math question.  And I'm sure a google search will turn up plenty of resources for you.

Comment: fast methods for aritmethic? Calculators, computer algebra system, ...

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: Oops, wasn't aware we had a tag for calculators.  I think that would be more appropriate than combinatorics.

Comment: Or maybe tag it numerical-methods ;)

Comment: I tried tagging it "abacus" but couldn't (yet). I tagged it "counting", which aliased to Combinatorics ;]

Comment: Use it as random number generator...

Comment: Try [*Use an Abacus*](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-an-Abacus)

Comment: Amzoti: thanks for putting it into google and posting the link. Alas, the abacus depicted in your story is a 4+1, this is a 10x10. Unless you care to post an answer explaining the similarities and differences, that does not help me much.